# HTML - CSS hr issue

Tags: css, html

Hi i had a problem today configuring my html page.
My sample code is:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <div style="width: 80%; float: left;">
        Text on div 80%
    </div>
    <div style="width: 20%; float:right">
        text on div 20%
    </div>
</div>
<hr>Text after hr
```

and as you can see the hr doesnt do his job because it dont show up where i set it to.

It should be like the following:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <div style="width: 80%; float: left;">
        Text on div 80%
    </div>
    <div style="width: 20%; float:right">
        text on div 20%
    </div>
</div>Only if i add text in this position the following hr works, how to fix it?
<hr>Text after hr
```

the problem is that after the div the hr doesnt show up!

I need to put some text before.. why it does that?

Comment: jdfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqaukpjf/3/

Comment: This is behaving correctly. Check the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<hr>` is there, only so small you need an electron microscope to see it. Try:

```
<hr style="width: 100%; float:left">Text ...
```

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/pqaukpjf/7/

**Also Note:**

Differences Between `HTML 4.01` and `HTML5`

- In HTML5, the `<hr>` tag defines a thematic break.
- In HTML 4.01, the `<hr>` tag represents a horizontal rule.

The `<hr>` tag is now defined in semantic terms, rather than presentational terms. All the layout attributes are removed in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pqaukpjf/3/)**

CSS:

```
hr{
    clear:both;
    height:2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```